# How to expose Kubernetes minikube app in domain

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

Exposed application on Windows 10 machine using Kubernetes minikube cluster and Nginx ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: testapp
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /testapp-web-dev
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: testapp-portal-web-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /testapp-api1-dev
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: testapp-portal-api1-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /testapp-api2-dev
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: testapp-portal-api2-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Added testapp entry into etc hosts and all is working fine locally. I can access application locally as *http://testapp/testapp-web-dev* or *http://testapp//testapp-api1-dev*

Now I'm wondering how could I expose this outside this computer which is in domain? I.e. computer name is machine1 and I want other users of domain access all its components as *http://machine1/testapp-web-dev http://machine1/testapp-api1-dev* or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your ingress configuration is specifying `testapp` as the host it's looking for in incoming requests.
If you change that to `machine1`, and the set the `machine1` host to resolve to the ip of the ingress controller service, the ingress controller should be able to successfully route requests to that host into the services on your cluster.

EDIT: You can follow [this useful guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) from the k8s docs that guides you through all of the required steps for setting up an ingress controller on minikube